# Can't start powershell.exe or use the server manager

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2022

Windows Server Datacenter 2022 used as Remote Desktop Server.
Powershell closes immediately after starting. I can start the Server Manager, but I get the same error. If I want to add or remove features or  if I want to use the server tools it also closes itself.

[image: the error message]

C:\Users\Administrator>powershell.exe

> There has been an unexpected error. Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Already tried:
-DISM
-SFC /scannow
-update .net Framework

Comment: Try `powershell.exe -noprofile`

Comment: Same error if I try it.

Comment: This question is not about programming. This question should go to https://serverfault.com/

Comment: What commands you have tried absolutely is NOT clear. Please clarify what you have tried so this question can be properly migrated.